# S3 PutObject operation gives Access Denied with IAM Role containing Policy granting access to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have an IAM role with a custom policy attached to it allowing access to an S3 bucket we'll call `foo-bar`. I've tried granting access to that specific resource, with `PutObject` and a couple other actions. That IAM Role is attached to an EC2 instance yet that EC2 instance does not have access to upload files when I use `aws s3 sync. s3://foo-bar`.

To test if it was an issue with the policy, I just granted S3:* to * resources, and it still won't upload.

`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:ListExports",
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}`

The error I get at the CLI is:

> upload failed: infrastructure\vpc.template to s3://foo-bar/infrastructure/vpc.template An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied

Is there something else I need to do in order to give it access? Why isn't the Policy attached to the IAM Role working?

Answer (score 0):

I tried running it with `--debug` to see what's going on.
This helped me discover that I have a local `.aws/credentials` file which overrode the IAMRole attached to the machine.

If you need the credentials file - you can have a different profile `[some name]` and use `--profile` to choose it.

HTH.

Comment: I'll have a look at this and see if that's the case.